# HTTP post from Android app to web service in Python Flask

Tags: java, android, python, http, flask

I need to send a Base64 string from Android application to a Python web service using HTTP post. 
I want to receive the string and return it on the webpage but the problem is that I can't receive the string.

On Android side, I chose a file from storage and encoded it in base64 string. Then, I used Volley to make the HTTP post request.
On the other side, I used Flask to build up the web service.

This is the MainActivity of my Android application:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button1;

Intent intent;
TextView text;
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    });


}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = null;
        uri = data.getData();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            final String conv = readTextFromUri(uri);
            //text.setText(conv);

            ////////REQUEST////////
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2:5000";

            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // response
                            text.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // error
                            text.setText("That didn't work!");
                        }
                    }
            ) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("conv", conv);

                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(postRequest);
            ////////END_REQUEST////////



        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }
}


            ////////ENCODE/////////
private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);
    try {
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    output64.close();

    String attachedFile = output.toString();

    return attachedFile;

}
            ////////THE END OF ENCODE////////

}
```

While, this is my Web Service in Python:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def call_cortex():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fileb64 = request.form['conv']
        return fileb64
    else:
        return 'Errore!'
```

At the moment, results are:

Android application shows

```
Response is + (part of base64 string)
```

Web Service shows "Errore!" that is

```
Method Not Allowed
```

Comment: try another RestClient like RestTemplate (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)?

Comment: also just delete GET from the allowed methods in your app routes since you are only using the request method to post data

Comment: So, do you think my problem is in the Android part?